# fence post setting regular quickcrete vs.fast setting

Tags: fence, post

hey so i've been building a couple fences lately and have been premixing with a concrete mixer i bought which was a couple hundred.
my question is can you mix the standard quikrete that comes in an 80lb yellow bag  $4.50 the same way you would do the fast setting quikrete that come only in the red 50 lb bag for $5.25?
im jaded by the price difference as well as the quantity difference.

do you recommend quikrete first then water or water then quikrete?

Answer (score 1):

If the setting time is not an issue, you can certainly use normal quickcrete - or save even more money by purchasing cement and aggregate (sand/gravel/rock) and really making use of the mixer.

Standard concrete mixing practice is to mix the dry materials and then add water. Common error is to add too much water and make the resulting concrete weak, though fence post setting is not exactly a high stress job, normally.

Comment: I agree people don’t realize how cheap a load of “concrete mix” is add a bag or 2 of Portland cement and since the op has the mixer could be going all day 1 scoop Portland cement to 5 scoops sand and gravel mix then 1/2 a coffee tin of water,  if the op likes doing it this way you can do porches and patio’s, I don’t do big jobs by hand any longer but used to and it all started with fence posts and a small mixer. +

Comment: is it acceptable to put the mix in the hole and just add water?

Answer (score 0):

Go with the cheapest because for fencepost it does not matter. What determines the lifetime of your fence is the wood rotting enclosed by the concrete and will happen no matter what. Mixing is a little water and then add the mix. Dryer mix makes stronger concrete. By the way I don't use concrete anymore. There are zinc plated metal stakes available which hold 4x4. The wood is not in the ground and installation is much faster and there is no set time for the concrete.

Comment: the posts im typically using are not the wooden 4x4 they are galvanized metal posts

Comment: Good for you. Saves u money in the long run. I would still use the cheapest concrete. I never seen it failing

Comment: so can i just put the mix in with the post in the hole and just add water or put water in the hole with the post then add concrete mix?

Comment: I seen people do that. You could also.just wait and let moisture and rain do the rest. That would work too. Don't overthink it to much, it's not rocket science. If it would be me I would add a little bit water in a wheelbarrow and add the mix. Than put the post into the whole and add the concrete. At the same time make sure it's level.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a concrete expert but have put in a few fence posts in my time. You definitely want to use your concrete mixer if you have one. This will ensure the cement is consistent. Ride Sun nailed it, you don't need an expensive mix for fence posts.

Wood or galvanized metal, your biggest challenge will be keeping the posts aligned while the concrete sets. That may be one of the reasons some people recommend a faster setting concrete mix. If you pack the holes are not very big, you can pack the concrete in tight but add some rock. (If you buy pre-mixed concrete, the rock will probably reduce the overall strength.

One other thing I learned the hard way, after you get your concrete almost completely poured, slope the concrete downward from the center just a bit so that water drains away from your posts.